# How to get the normalized XML documentation name of a type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, xml-documentation

How is it possible to get the name of the type which corresponds to the name used in XML documentation output file?

I thought that XML documentation uses full names, but this is not the case. For example the full name of `Collection<long>` is:

> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]])

while the XML documentation corresponding to a property of type `Collection<long>` is:

> System.Collections.Generic.ICollection{System.Int64}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML documentation uses the fully qualified class name; e.g. the namespace and the class name. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx

Your example (with PublicKey) is the fully qualified **AssemblyName** of the class; which is normally used only when you need to dynamically load the Type.

The XML documentation convention for a generic is to use '{T}' to make it easier to type, as in .  "Collection" is not used because '<' is special in XML!

Comment: The result of `typeof(List<int>).FullName` is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]. Those generic type parameters are tricky.

Comment: @mike z: when you use `typeof(List<int>).FullName`, you're in the same case as the one I described in my question. Richard Schneider explained why this is the wrong approach and that the type should still be decomposed before using `FullName` on different parts.

Comment: @mikez, you have a point.  Didn't have time to write a Unit Test.  But I think the OP gets gist of my answer.